# Angular Material 6 datepicker different formats in same component

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I need to select two different date formats (YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM) in two mat datepicker fields in one component view.

I'm using angular 6.0.3 and material 6.4.7.

I configured datepicker format to YYYY-MM-DD in app module using MAT_DATE_FORMATS and it works globally but I need to override this format to YYYY-MM in a few datepicker fields as I wrote above.
Unfortunatelly I have no idea how I can achieve this.

Could You help me please?

Parts of my code:

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-invoice-list',
      templateUrl: './invoice-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./invoice-list.component.css']
    })
    export class InvoiceListComponent {

      filterForm: FormGroup;

      @ViewChild('month_picker') month_picker;

      constructor() {
        this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
          assigned_date_from: new FormControl(),
          assigned_date_to: new FormControl(),
          assigned_month: new FormControl(),
        });
      }
    }

<div class="container" [formGroup]="filterForm">
  <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="start">
      <div fxFlex="32%">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="date_from_picker" (focus)="date_from_picker.open()" formControlName="assigned_date_from" placeholder="Date from">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date_from_picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #date_from_picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="32%">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="date_to_picker" (focus)="date_to_picker.open()" formControlName="assigned_date_to" placeholder="Date to">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date_to_picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #date_to_picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <!-- In below input I want month year format - YYYY-MM - so different than default format in above fields -->
      <div fxFlex="32%">
          <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="month_picker" (focus)="month_picker.open()" formControlName="assigned_month" placeholder="Month">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="month_picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #month_picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use viewChild?

Comment: I thought about viewChild, but viewChild variable is shared for all datepicker in my view, right? In this way every changes from component on this datepicker (viewChild variable) will apply for all datepicker fields in my view

Comment: No i can help you but I need some time.can you put your html and ts file.

Comment: Thank You!! I added parts of my code in my post

Comment: No need of adding viewChildren. I'll post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. 
In your Html

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="month_picker" (focus)="month_picker.open()" [value] = "selectedMonth" placeholder="Month">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="month_picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #month_picker  
              startView="multi-year"
              (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, month_picker)"></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

In your .ts

```
    selectedMonth = new Date();

    chosenMonthHandler(normlizedMonth, datepicker) {
        var tempDate = JSON.stringify(normlizedMonth).replace("\"",'').split("-")
        var month = parseInt(tempDate[1])
        var year = month == 12?parseInt(tempDate[0])+1:parseInt(tempDate[0])
        var year = month == 12?parseInt(tempDate[0])+1:parseInt(tempDate[0])
        month = month == 12?1:month+1;
        this.selectedMonth = new Date(year + "-" + month)
        console.log(year + " " + month)
        datepicker.close();
      }
```

This works well.but show the selected date as 1 after select a month.But I think this fulfills your requirements.

Comment: I tried this already but it doesn't work. Start view when I open datepicker is months list but when I select month there is day to select and finally date is displayed in my global format :(

Comment: aah i'm looking for that. it is a hard work but I'll do it for you.

Comment: Asanka thank You a lot! I would simplify getting the date from normalizeMonth variable:
normlizedMonth.format('YYYY-MM');
because normalizedMonth is moment object.
So few lines of code less :)
By the way I have one small question - what place do You recommend to store this function (chosenMonthHandler) if I use this in a few places/compontents. Any service? What is best practice for this?

Answer (score 5):

```
http://brickydev.com/angular-material-datepicker-with-many-custom-date-formats/
```

I found this link and this solution worked for me.

step 1: Create a directive

```
ng generate directive customDateFormat
```

step 2:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';

export const FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomeDateFormats]',
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: FORMAT }],
})
export class CustomeDateFormatsDirective {
  constructor() {}
}
```

step 3: use this directive in the template.

```
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appCustomeDateFormats>
            <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
            <input
              matInput
              [matDatepicker]="startDate"
              formControlName="from_date"
            />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle
              matSuffix
              [for]="startDate"
            ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker touchUi #startDate></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If you're looking for a way to have a couple static formats, it is
   [possible](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrzg5?file=app%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts).

   Unfortunately, if you want to have it be dynamic based on a
   directive input (e.g. ) This won't
   work because there isn't currently a mechanism to tell the
   datepicker that the format has updated.

   More information can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12035#issuecomment-515509919)