# Angular Material Datepicker - Month & Year ONLY

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want my angular material datepicker to only show month/year. NO days.

Here is my datepicker:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I saw previous threads stating setting the mode to:

```
md-mode="month"
```

The above does not work anymore. What is the solution now?

Comment: Create two selects, one with month and another with year. This will be simplest solution to handle with. The reason for going to calendar is mainly for days mapping only. For example, refer facebook registration page for DOB field.

Comment: Using selects would require manual input of numerous years?

Comment: @user10181542 - You can fill an array with the method suggested in [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/fill-array-javascript) and use `*ngFor` in the template to add these `option`s to the `select` element.

Comment: I have made a stackblitz with minimal consideration on looping years. For months, i would suggest to hardcode name, if not use, moment to get local translation, depending on the requiremet. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyyqpn

Answer (score 13):

Here is a code that worked for me. I see you are trying something similar. Hope it helps.

The `.html` file:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp2" [min]="sixMonthsAgo" [max]="today" placeholder="Select a Date" (click)="openDatePicker(dp2)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp2 startView="multi-year" (monthSelected)="closeDatePicker($event, dp2)"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The snippet from `.ts` file:

```
  this.today = new Date();
  this.sixMonthsAgo = new Date();
  this.sixMonthsAgo.setMonth(this.today.getMonth() - 6);

  openDatePicker(dp) {
    dp.open();
  }

  closeDatePicker(eventData: any, dp?:any) {
    // get month and year from eventData and close datepicker, thus not allowing user to select date
    dp.close();    
  }
```

Comment: Did you also find a way to change the display format to just display month and year?

Comment: @VincentSels I believe this would only display the month and year once selected. You may also refer the official documentation around this - https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: @VincentSels you can hide the input the `display: none;` and get the form value and format it with date pipe.

here is what I mean: 
`<div>{{ monthForm.get('month').value | date: 'MMM YYYY' }}</div>`

Answer (score 4):

I have worked out a solution, fully relying on the example given in the official Angular Material documentation :

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months

The example with code works fine but there is still a navigation to 'month' view in the calendar when user clicks on years in the header

[image]

Here is a turnaround : in the TS of the custom component where the

`<mat-datepicker #dp startView="multi-year" (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)" (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, datePicker)"></mat-datepicker>`

is declared as in the Angular Material link, I add :

```
@ViewChild('datePicker') public dp;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dp.openedStream.subscribe(async _ => {
    while (this.dp._popupComponentRef.instance._calendar == null)
      await this.__delay__(100)

    this.dp._popupComponentRef.instance._calendar._calendarHeaderPortal._attachedHost._attachedRef.instance.currentPeriodClicked = function () {        
    
        // redefine here calendar navigation in header
        
        if (this.calendar.currentView == 'month')
            this.calendar.currentView = 'year'
        
        this.calendar.currentView = this.calendar.currentView == 'year' ? 'multi-year' : 'year';
    }
  })
}
```

That way you can customize the navigation from the header...

Comment: this is actually pretty straightforward in the docs, just use CSS to disable that button.

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-period-button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-arrow {
  display: none;
}

works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement is to show "MMMM YYYY" format on the input element.
"MMMM YYYY" format is "Month Year".
Want to create custom date format and apply to the mat-datepicker.

in the HTML

```
<mat-label>For the Month</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" name="CalMonth" formControlName="CalMonth">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker1 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

in the .ts typescript

want to import **material-moment-adapter** ,**material/core** and
**moment**

To install the material-moment-adapter

> npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter

> npm i angular-moment

```
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL', 
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MMMM YYYY', // this is the format showing on the input element
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY', // this is showing on the calendar 
  },
};
```

after that add to the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-monthselector',
  templateUrl: './monthselector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./monthselector.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
```

after that add the format to the relevant controller

```
this.UIForm = new FormGroup({
      CalMonth: new FormControl(moment()),
    });
```

follow above steps one by one and you can customize the date format to **"Month Year"** .

you can change anyother date format as well, only change this

> **dateInput: 'MMMM YYYY',**

Thanks,

Indika Pradeep

Comment: I did this and it change all datepicker in the component, so in the view i see all picker like this: "01/2022". how to apply this to only one while other picker format will remain the default like this: ''01/01/2022"

Comment: set a provider only for your input by @Directive. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814736/2927851 with example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrzg5?file=app%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts

Answer (score 3):

This is surprisingly not straightforward.. I have found the "official" way here

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ekjvrbglvnb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

Code in .html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Code in .ts

```
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';


 @ViewChild('picker') datePickerElement = MatDatepicker;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.datePickerElement) 
    console.log(this.datePickerElement['opened'])  
   
    setTimeout(() => {
          this.datePickerElement['_datepickerInput']._dateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL', 
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MMMM YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY', 
  },
};
    },1000)


  }
```

This is working fine for me.
Date format will display like below screenshot
[image]

Comment: error in _datepickerInput

Comment: remove _ before '_datepickerInput'

sendo assim

this.datePickerElement['datepickerInput']._dateFormats =  .....

Answer (score 2):

You can use these two handlers (`chosenYearHandler` & `chosenMonthHandler`) , and the formatting to show only month and year :

**TS :**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp
                  startView="multi-year"
                  (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                  (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS:**

```
.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-period-button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.example-month-picker .mat-calendar-arrow {
  display: none;
}
```

For more explanations : https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Answer (score 0):

In my case I hade a dynamic amount of inputs so I couldn't insert the data into the form control like in the documentation:
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#datepicker-views-selection

this was my solution:

```
  setDateHandler(dateEvent: Moment,datepicker: MatDatepicker<any>) {
datepicker._selectedChanged.next(dateEvent);
datepicker.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dashboardForm = new FormGroup({
    dataFilter: new FormControl(new Date()),
  });
 
 onMonthSelected(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.picker.close();
    console.log(event);
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="picker">
  <form [formGroup]="dashboardForm">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="dataFilter" />
  </form>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker startView="multi-year" (monthSelected)="onMonthSelected($event)"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```