# Material Design Date Picker that only shows the months

Tags: angular, material-design

I am working with the Material Design component library in Angular

https://material.angular.io/

My client has requested that I have the date range picker only show the months and years, not the days.

This:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

As the images show, the component allows you to select the month, but then it goes into that month and shows you the days of the month. My client wants to be able to select a range of, for instance, January to march on the interface shown in the first image.

I have gone through their documentation and cannot seem to find an option to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Check the last example of the material examples [Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: There is a similar stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676974/angular-material-datepicker-month-year-only). See if it helps.